# Order of elements in a noncyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If we have group of order 21 that is not cyclic. Then that group does not have element of order 21. Why is that?

Comment: Assume that a group $G$ of order $21$ admits an element $g\in G$ of order $21$ then the group generated by $g$, $\langle g\rangle$ is of order ...? Conclusion?

Comment: I know that you are new here.but this seems to be a the basic requirement for a cyclic group isn't it.?jsut see the definition of a cyclic group and you will get an answer for yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very definition of "cyclic group" is: $G$ is cyclic if for some $g \in G$, we have $G = \langle g \rangle = \{g^n : n \in \mathbf Z\}$, note that the order of $\langle g \rangle$ - the subgroup generated by $g$ - is the order of $g$. If $G$ had an element $g$ of order 21, $\langle g \rangle$ would be a subgroup of order 21, hence equal $G$. But $G \ne \langle g \rangle$ for every $g \in G$, as $G$ is non-cyclic. Therefore no element of $G$ can have order 21.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the element of order 21, denote it with $g$. What does it mean that $g$ is of order 21? Well it means that $g^{21} =e$.

Now look at $\{g,g^2,g^3,..g^{21}\}$ this is a subset of our group and it has 21 distinguished members. and if the group is not cyclic then there  must be another element that does not appear in that set, Thus there are at list 22 members in the group, and that's a contradiction.